# Swift SceneKit node scroll

Tags: swift, scenekit, scene

I implemented my own method of scrolling the sphere, but when scrolling, it feels like lags

when I use the standard scrolling method (allowsCameraControl = true), when the sphere is jerked sharply to the side (like a swipe), the sphere will scroll for some time before stopping, in my case not. How can I do the same?

```
// Set scene settings
sceneView.scene = scene

cameraOrbit = SCNNode()
cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.name = "camera"
camera = SCNCamera()

// camera stuff
camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
camera.orthographicScale = 5
camera.zNear = 1
camera.zFar = 100


// initially position is far away as we will animate moving into the globe
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 50)
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraOrbit = SCNNode()
cameraOrbit.addChildNode(cameraNode)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

// Material
let blueMaterial = SCNMaterial()
blueMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "earth2")
blueMaterial.shininess = 0.05
blueMaterial.multiply.contents = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.7, green: 0.7, blue: 0.7, alpha: 1.0)

let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 2)
sphere.segmentCount = 300
sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
earthNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
earthNode.name = "sphere"
earthNode.geometry?.materials = [blueMaterial]
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)
earthNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, 0)

sceneView.allowsCameraControl = false
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = true
sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.rotationSensitivity = 0.4

let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)


    @objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognize: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognize.numberOfTouches == 1 { //leftRightAttenuation = 5.0
            if (gestureRecognize.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed) {
                let scrollWidthRatio = Float(gestureRecognize.velocity(in: gestureRecognize.view!).x) / (leftRightAttenuation * 10000) 
                let scrollHeightRatio = Float(gestureRecognize.velocity(in: gestureRecognize.view!).y) / (leftRightAttenuation * 10000)
                cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.y += Float(-2 * Double.pi) * scrollWidthRatio
                cameraOrbit.eulerAngles.x += Float(-Double.pi) * scrollHeightRatio
            }
        }
    }
```

Video with standart scroll (`allowsCameraControl = true`)

https://youtu.be/0BL0mY26ZkY

Video with my own scroll (`allowsCameraControl = false`)

https://youtu.be/ZwRgJMDZpmA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

https://github.com/gadsden/SceneKit-Quaternion-Rotations

Contains 3 different methods of how to rotate objects.

Comment: just a little hint: allowsCameraControl = true does not scroll the object, it scrolls/rotates the camera around the object - there are several different control behaviours that you can use when allowsCameraControl = true