# How can I rotate a SCNNode about its own center using a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a scene view. If allowsCameraControl is true and I pan using one finger, the model rotates about its center. I want to achieve this same result, when allowsCameraControl is false. I want to move the part, not the point of view.

I have the following function...

```
  private func rotateModels(with startingLocation: CGPoint, endingLocation: CGPoint, node: SCNNode) {
    let radius: Float = 600
    let panTranslation = CGPoint(x: startingLocation.x - endingLocation.x, y: startingLocation.y - endingLocation.y)
    let panTranslationDistance = sqrtf(Float(pow(panTranslation.x, 2) + pow(panTranslation.y, 2)))
    let angle = 3 * asin((panTranslationDistance/2)/radius)
    let axis = simd_float3(x: Float(-panTranslation.y), y: Float(-panTranslation.x), z: 0)
    let quat = simd_quatf(angle: angle, axis: axis)
    node.simdLocalRotate(by: quat)
  }
```

It appears to work, but sometimes it stretches or distorts the model.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This might help (the link in the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677512/swift-scenekit-node-scroll

Comment: Thanks ZAY. That did provide some insight.

Comment: I think the problem was that I was not normalizing. With the help of the above link, I fixed the math. But the resulting motion was not smooth. It would fight the user's gesture. I ended up manipulating the camera instead. That works well.